# Angular 6: Switch b/w Tabs

Tags: angular

im working on an Angular 6 application, what im trying to do here is, As soon as the user inserts information in the visible input fields and clicks save, i want the view to change to "Products" tab.
Products is a separate components and has its own template as well.
Appreciate the help
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a variable to selectedIndex Input in mat-tab-group.

```
index = 0; // Or tab you want mat-tab-group to start with
```

And use it like this

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="index">
```

And create a button function on click that changes index to number assigned to your Product tab, since it is your second tab, that number is 1.

```
<button (click)="index = 1">
```

You can read more on Input and Outputs of mat-tab here: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api and check the examples.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you are using matTabGroup with nested tabs. MatTabGroup allows you to set the start tab with [selectedIndex].

**Example:**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="1">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```